# Set server time on JQuery timePicker NOW button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I'm using opencart Version 1.5.1.3, where we are using jQuery time picker so many times, currently NOW button sets a system time, but i want to set a current server time on NOW button.

my site server is running in a USA, so i want to set CST timezone for my all timepicker.

right now code look like below line,

```
$('.time').timepicker({showSecond: true,timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',defaultTimezone:'-0600',showTimezone:false});
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: which time picker are you using?

Comment: @Circadian : jQuery-ui-timepicker-addon

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion [here](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/pull/475) I understand that if you set the `defaultTimezone` to what your server has and leave `showTimezone: false` then you will achieve what you ask.

I have not tested this

Comment: please check my updated question with current line of code. if any changes u can suggest me.